# ffmpeg command to merge file with good quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for a better command that can merge both audio & video files into one with a better quality.

I found this command from Muaz Khan's WebRTC APIs.

```
ffmpeg -i {$audioFile} -i {$videoFile} -map 0:0 -map 1:0 {$mergedFileName}
```

Later on server i had to add "-strict -2" with this command as on server it says that above command is experimental if I still want to use it you should add "-strict -2" with it.

It is working well but my video file (.webm) with size 2.2MB and audio file (.wav) with size 1.5MB was merged into a new file (.webm) with size 422.5KB. This new video file is having lag.

Also I want the meta information for duration of video is already written on the resulting video file.

Is there any command which can give the merged file without lagging and both video and audio of the new file are of good quality ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i {$audioFile} -i {$videoFile} -map 0:0 -c:a libopus -map 1:0 -c:v copy {$mergedFileName}
```

This will encode only the audio, leaving the video intact. Use `libvorbis` if `libopus` isn't present in your FFmpeg.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: Both didn't work. Showing me error Unknown encoder 'libvorbis' &  Unknown encoder 'libopus'.
I am using ffmpeg version 2.2.5

Comment: That's 18 months old. Get a recent binary - one with at least one of the two libraries included/linked.

Comment: And nothing will improve on the original video quality. Best you can hope for is that the conversion doesn't degrade the quality. The video stream copy will ensure that.

Comment: Found the problem. Actually my merging is working well, but the code after merging is causing a problem in video. Should I open another question for it or edit this one?